# Does Watch Series 5 work with iPhone SE?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

On Apple's [fine print](https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch) it says:

> Apple Watch Series 5 requires an iPhone 6s or later with iOS 13 or later.

So I'm not sure whether this implies iPhone SE as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the iPhone SE is supported by Apple Watch Series 5 as it was released after the iPhone 6s in March 2016, as long as the device is running iOS 13 or later.

I can confirm the device functions perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the iPhone SE was released the year *after* the iPhone 6s, one can safely assume that it will work with the Apple Watch Series 5. That's what the 'or later' means.

I can find nothing after a few minutes of Googling, (which you can do yourself as well,) that tells me the iPhone SE is not compatible.

Comment: What do you mean by "that tells me otherwise"?